# Dont display duplicate records in an xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am looping an xml file to display it's content and the structure is:

```
<PRODUCT>
<ID><![CDATA[100860]]></ID>
<NAME><![CDATA[Blah blah blah blah]]></NAME>
<DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[An amazing shoe]]></DESCRIPTION>
<CATEGORY_NAME><![CDATA[SHOES]]></CATEGORY_NAME>
<MANUFACTURER><![CDATA[Club]]></MANUFACTURER>
<PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA[38.40]]></PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA[19.90]]></PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRODUCT_URL><![CDATA[http://www.domain.com]]></PRODUCT_URL>
<IMAGE_URL><![CDATA[http://www.domain.com/100_a.jpg]]></IMAGE_URL>
<THUMBNAIL_URL><![CDATA[]]></THUMBNAIL_URL>
</PRODUCT>
```

So far i am using the code bellow to echo each

```
<?php
// specify url of xml file
$urln = "xml_feeds.xml";
// get xml file contents
$xmln = simplexml_load_file($urln);

echo '<div style="width: 1000px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border:1px solid #000;">';
foreach($xmln->PRODUCT as $PRODUCTS)
{

echo '<p style="background-color: #069; color: #fff;">';
echo "[";
echo $PRODUCTS->CATEGORY_NAME;
echo "]";
echo "</p>";

}
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>';
?>
```

The Code is working good so far, but how is it possible to do not show me duplicate records. And i mean do not show me the same CATEGORY_NAME (category names)

Thank you!!

Comment: store first category name in some variable , and compare the next record's category name to it. if match do not display , else , display and update the variable's value with new category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array containing the category names, use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) to remove the duplicates, and then loop through the new array to echo out the elements:

```
$category_name_array = array(); 

foreach($xmln->PRODUCT as $products)
{
    $category_name_array[] = (string) $products->CATEGORY_NAME
}

$category_name_array = array_unique($category_name_array);

foreach ($category_name_array as $category_name) {
    echo '<p style="background-color: #069; color: #fff;">';
    echo "[$category_name]";
    echo "</p>";
}
```